# planning_scene_warehouse_viewer crashes when using secondary IK

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS Industrial on Electric. Everything works except when I try to plan a new trajectory using the secondary planner (interpolated IK), planning_scene_warehouse_viewer crashes:

**[planning_scene_warehouse_viewer-10] process has died [pid 3263, exit code -11].**

I have tried it with the stock code from the repository with the sia10d:

**$ roslaunch sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_sia10d_mesh.launch**

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37016/planning_scene_warehouse_viewer-crashes-when-using-secondary-ik/) by [m.anderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2685/m.anderson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2012-06-21**:
Michael, are you using the trunk, electric, or feurte branches.

**Comment by [m.anderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2685/m.anderson/) on 2012-06-21**:
Electric branch

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2012-06-23**:
The secondary IK might not be set up. I'll have to check to be sure.

**Comment by [m.anderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2685/m.anderson/) on 2012-06-24**:
It looks like it may be possible just to use the pr2_arm_kinematics_node. I haven't tried it yet but it looks generic enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears the the secondary path planner was added in Fuerte.  It's not clear whether the arm wizard in Fuerte would populate the secondary planner.  Since most arm navigation packages were generated in Electric, I don't expect any of them are configured for the secondary planner.

I have added a bug to the ROS-Industrial [Bug list](https://code.google.com/p/swri-ros-pkg/issues/detail?id=14).

It's not a high priority at this point to fix since the transition to [MoveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/) will make some of these things obsolete.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2012-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-07-01**:
I doubt that. I think I once used the secondary planner back in Electric. I also think, that the Willow guys use this planner to move from the pre-grasping to the grasping pose.Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-07-01**:
I doubt that. I think I once used the secondary planner back in Electric. I also think, that the Willow guys use this planner to move from the pre-grasping to the grasping pose. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.